# disable dismiss hyperlink and message on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When we run any method of Google App Script,a message appears on Google Spreadsheet with dismiss hyperlink. 
For Example:

**Running Script *methodname* Dismiss hyperlink**

I would like to know if there is any option to disable the message and dismiss hyperlink that appears on Google Spreadsheet when any function is executed at the back ground. In not , please share what alternates are available to hide this out.

Comment: No. That message disappears by itself after running successfully. If it fails, it's replaced with a red message.

Comment: My best guess is that you have no control over those popups. But if I stumble on anything, I will comment here.

Answer (score 0):

It is within a `div` of class `docs-butterbar-container` so on your own machine, you could add

```
.docs-butterbar-container {
  display:none;
}
```

to a user stylesheet.

But if you are hoping to hide it from other others of your sheets/scripts then your likely out of luck, unless you have means of rolling out user stylesheets.

I also wouldn't recommend hiding this. It's useful.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. But my requirement was to hide it from other users(collaborators).In case a function is running and they click on dismiss the function would come to an end, and the non technical people might not get any clue if function is running or stopped.

Comment: dismiss doesn't cancel the script - only when you see cancel does it stop it running. dismiss makes the message go away.